# How to check if there are blank period of posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to check if there was a blank period that have no posts.

I wrote like this:

```
Post.all.pluck(:date).sort.each_cons(2).any?{|i,j| (i - j).abs > 7 }
```

Is there a better implementation?
I'm not good at database functions. Is there a function for it in `Postgresql`.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit expensive, you could do a cross join (which really is a cartesian join) and calculate directly in the database. Also, here I assume that the columns are Datetime fields instead of Date.

**For MySQL**

```
Post.
  joins('CROSS JOIN posts p2').
  where('TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date, p2.date) > 7').
  present?
```

Note that the difference needed to be converted to days if you want 7 days period.

**For Postgres**, do check out the relevant function at the [postgres datetime docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html). You might have to do something like this:

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM ABS(d1 - d2))
```